# What is difference between U-boot.bin and uImage.bin

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, u-boot

I am confused between the `u-boot.bin` and `uImage.bin`. I guess `uImage.bin` is nothing but the compressed version of `u-boot.bin` and it size should be less than `u-boot.bin`. But in my build environment what I found is `u-boot.bin` size is lesser than `uImage.bin`.

Could anybody let me know what is difference between `u-boot.bin` and `uImage.bin`??

Comment: Are you sure uImage.bin isn't actually a Linux kernel and root filesystem image packed together, which uboot would in turn load?

Comment: You mean to say U-boot is a bootloader which will load kernel+file-system image that is nothing but uImage??

Comment: u-boot is definitely a bootloader.  uImage *sounds* to me *more* like a kernel + filesystem image than a different packaging of u-boot, but I can't say that it definitely is *for your particular example*.  How big is each?

Comment: I don't have the exact size right now but can say uImage.img is bigger than u-boot.img,I guess uboot.bin is ubootloader image and uImage is image which comes from “raw” ELF image.

Comment: No.  uImage should be a compressed file, or else it is misnamed  If it's bigger, then that points to it being a compressed version of something else - such as Linux.  And that would fit with the traditional usage of naming on uboot/linux systems.

Comment: Yes Chris, "I guess uboot.bin is ubootloader image and uImage is image which comes from “raw” ELF image" ,What I meant was after compression of “raw” ELF image we get the uImage

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`uboot.bin` is the bootloader, i.e. uboot, `uImage.bin` is the kernel image

Usually, in embedded systems the NAND flash is partitioned in four parts:

1. A partition for the bootloader (here goes uboot.bin)
2. A small partition where uboot saves its environment variables
3. A partition for the kernel (here goes uImage.bin)
4. A partition for the rootfs

Comment: And on OMAP-based systems there's a another: A partition for the fist-stage bootloader that loads the main bootloader (e.g. uBoot).

Comment: X-loader is a small first stage boot loader derived from the u-boot base code to be loaded into the internal static ram by the OMAP ROM code. Because the internal static ram is very small (64k-32k), x-loader is stripped down to the essentials and is used to initialize memory and enough of the peripheral devices to access and load the second stage loader (u-boot) into main memory.

Comment: Thanks Ottavio for your answer,I would like to know how uboot.bin picks the uImage.bin .Is there any standard procedure.Could you let me know any good docs for the same?

Comment: This is hardware dependent. Usually what you can do with uboot, you copy the kernel from the NAND to ram and then you just into is. To have an idea, you che check this http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Booting_Linux_kernel_using_U-Boot#NAND_Flash_.28jffs2_image_as_rootfs.29 , but I repeat, it's a bit depending on your hardware

Comment: Environment variables can be there in the same partition as the kernel, no need of separate partition. Also on some platform there will not be any partition for uboot E.g i.MX.

Answer (score 0):

**uboot.bin** is the binary file of U-boot bootloader.
**uImage** is a small kernel image with modified header for Uboot enabling U-boot to load this kernel image